# csrsv2Info_t in CUDA 12.0

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

Recently I am deploying my CUDA project in Ubuntu which is equipped with CUDA 12.0. My project is written in CUDA 11.2 in which `csrsv2Info_t` and related functions are supported, see [11.2.Doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.2.0/cusparse/index.html#csrsv2Info_t). However, `csrsv2Info_t` is announced deprecated in the next major version of CUDA(12) in [CUDA 11.4](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.4.0/cusparse/index.html#csrsv2Info_t). So expected error occurs during deployment in CUDA 12.0:

```
error: identifier "csrsv2Info_t" is undefined
```

But When I go to check [CUDA 12.0.Doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/12.0.0/cusparse/index.html), there is nothing about `csrsv2Info_t` deprecated or something. Instead, there is a paragraph in section 8:

> In particular, the solution of sparse triangular linear systems is implemented in two phases. First, during the analysis phase, the sparse triangular matrix is analyzed to determine the dependencies between its elements by calling the appropriate `csrsv2_analysis()` function. The analysis is specific to the sparsity pattern of the given matrix and to the selected cusparseOperation_t type. The information from the analysis phase is stored in the parameter of type `csrsv2Info_t` that has been initialized previously with a call to `cusparseCreateCsrsv2Info()`.

> Second, during the solve phase, the given sparse triangular linear system is solved using the information stored in the `csrsv2Info_t` parameter by calling the appropriate `csrsv2_solve()` function. The solve phase may be performed multiple times with different right-hand sides, while the analysis phase needs to be performed only once. This is especially useful when a sparse triangular linear system must be solved for a set of different right-hand sides one at a time, while its coefficient matrix remains the same.

> Finally, once all the solves have completed, the opaque data structure pointed to by the `crsv2Info_t` parameter can be released by calling cusparseDestroyCsrsv2Info()

It seems the official document has not been updated on time. I've checked the `cusparse.h` in CUDA 12.0 in which `csrsv2Info_t` has already been removed, now I want to know what the replaced one is, could anyone give me some related information?

Comment: here is a viable path: do not use CUDA 12.0, use CUDA 11.8 instead. according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA, CUDA 11.8 support both GPU 4090Ti(sm_89) and the functions that I mentioned above. I am still curious about the replaced one of csrsv2Info_t too.

Comment: I think the ["Generic API"](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/12.0.0/cusparse/index.html#generic-api-functions) is used instead.

Comment: You could [file a bug](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-report-a-bug/67911) about the docs including outdated features.